# Should ion-nav-view work with angular ui-router v.1.0.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ion-nav-view

I am working on a project that uses `angular 1.6.26` and `ionic 3.2.0`. So far it was also using `angular-ui-router 4.2.0`, but I decided to upgrade it to `1.0.5`. The problem is I cannot make it work with ionic's `ion-nav-view` directive.

I have `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` (without name parameter) node in my index.html but I'm getting `Cannot read property '@' of undefined` error on app loading. I managed to establish that this is related to the `name` attribute of the directive as the "@" changes to "someName@" when I add name attribute.

Here is the place where the error occurs https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1/blob/master/js/angular/directive/navView.js#L188

Looks like `$state.current` has no `locals` property.

I thought there is something wrong with my route config, but when I replaced `ion-nav-view` with `ui-view` it worked like a charm. Is there anybody that had this issue already or knows what it is caused by? Any help here would be very appreciated.